# Read in expressions - EOF while reading - in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'd like to read in a (longer) file in Closure that contains proper LISP syntax. So I think the best way to do so would be to avoid strings. I tried to use the following function:

```
(defn my-reader 
    [filename]
    (with-open [r (java.io.PushbackReader. (reader filename))]
        (binding [*read-eval* false]
            (loop [expr (read r :eof :end)]
                (if (= :end expr)
                    (print "The End")
                    (do
                        (println expr)
                        (recur (read r :eof :end))))))))
```

However, this throws a EOF while reading error.

As a workaround, I've built:

```
(defn my-reader 
    [filename]
    (with-open [r (java.io.PushbackReader. (reader filename))]
     (binding [*read-eval* false]
        (loop [expr (read r :eof :end)]
            (if (= -1 expr)
                (print "The End")
            (recur (try 
                (print (read r :eof :end))
                (catch Exception e -1))))))))
```

But that's pretty ugly. My attempt with the help of [How to use clojure.edn/read to get a sequence of objects in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234880/how-to-use-clojure-edn-read-to-get-a-sequence-of-objects-in-a-file/15237012#15237012) was:

```
(defn my-reader 
    [filename]
    (with-open [r (java.io.PushbackReader. (reader filename))]
        (binding [*read-eval* false]
            (let [expr (repeatedly (partial read r :eof :theend))]
    (dorun (map println (take-while (partial not= :theend) expr)))))))
```

And didn't work neither (EOF while reading). However, the solution in the other thread works fine (and `edn` seem to be the preferred way to read in files). Nevertheless, I'd like to know why my attempts do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantics of clojure.core/read are a bit different than clojure.tools.reader.edn/read.

The arity-3 version takes arguments

1. `stream` the input stream
2. `eof-error?` a boolean specifying whether you want `read` to throw an exception at EOF
3. `eof-value` a sentinel value to return when EOF is reached

So, I think you want to replace `(read r :eof :end)` with `(read r false :end)` as keywords are truthy.

Comment: ...and after hours it works like a charm. Thank you!